# Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty in Meteorjs

Tags: meteor, meteorite

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty '/path/disk/folder/.meteor/local/build-garbage-     qb4wp0/programs/ctl/packages'
```

I already looked over this website for this problem and known what are maybe the causes of this error and also tried them. I also tried their solutions and I can manage to always reset the project.

The problem is, whenever the project is reset, on the first run of the project,it will run smoothly and no errors will occur but after some moment or changes to my project like error checking, adding packages or changing some stuff... that error will occur.

I have no  idea on how to fix this problem and my temporary solution is to always create another meteor project and put all my project files and also install all packages I used.

Badly need help.

Comment: Perhaps `meteor reset` will be an easier workaround.

Comment: Reset doesn't work directly. It says that meteor is still running, so I have to go to terminal and kill it there directly, after killing the process, it shows another error doing meteor reset. So the last workaround I'm doing is to delete directly the contents of .meteor/local/build and .meteor/local/db . After resetting the project, the project will run smoothly unless I changed something to the document or add a package or get an error on the project.

Comment: `Error: ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty '/media/Meteor/hash/.meteor/local/build-garbage-191qm6k/programs/server/packages'` 


That's what I get after killing the meteor process and doing meteor reset.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when running Meteor.js on a Vagrant machine. For additional background, I had created a symbolic link for the MongoDB's db folder, since I had faced a locking issue ([solution I used for that was described elsewhere](http://lookonmyworks.co.uk/2013/06/18/running-meteor-in-a-vagrant-virtualbox/)).

Following that, my setup was as follows:

> /vagrant/.meteor/local/db -> /home/vagrant/my_project_db (symbolic link)

That solved the problem I had with MongoDB's lock, but everytime any source file changed, meteor would crash with the same exception that you faced. Deleting files didn't help, neither did meteor reset.

Fortunately enough it was remedied by changing the folder structure to this:

> /vagrant/.meteor/local -> /home/vagrant/my_project_local (symbolic link)

What I did was as simple as moving the Meteor.js's local folder out from the shared folder and only referencing to that with a symbolic link:

```
cd /vagrant/.meteor
mv local /home/vagrant/my_project_local
ln -s /home/vagrant/my_project_local local
```

In the end all is good. The error is long gone and feedback cycle is much shorter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your last recipe! I am doing the same but in the Docker container. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the folder it tells you are issues. I think its trying to clean them but there's an unhandled type of situation (it has files in it and its using rm instead of a recursive one)

Remove

```
/media/Meteor/hash/.meteor/local/build-garbage-**
```

(Anything with build-garbade in the name). Also you might want to check whether your permissions are right this might have been caused initially with something to do with incorrectly set permissions, maybe you ran as `sudo` once? If you're on a Mac you could use repair disk permissions.

Comment: Deleted them too and the same thing happens. Permissions are not an issue.

Comment: @o2kevin it might be worth mentioning too that this is with your meteor installation as from the path above it is in the meteor install directory and not your app's directory.